# API JSON GET - listen to the changes

Tags: angular, angular9

In my Angular app I am fetching data from an api service which provides me JSON data.
I have several values in fetched data. See the example:

```
{
    "StartDate": "2020-07-06 23:29:01",
    "Visits": 1,
    "Clicks": 1,
    "FormSuccess": 0,
    "FormFailures": 0,
}
```

On my Angular App I have made a dashboard which shows these numbers.
As you can see these numbers will change by time...

Is there a "smarter" way to put a listener to this API Get url and whenever changes happens to these, it should refresh my dashboard with the new figures?

my JSON get looks like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get("https://myapiurl/info", this.httpOptions)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.jsonArray = data;
      })
  }
```

Comment: you may need to use SignalR framework to make it real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WebSockets for this

[Similar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628416/listening-for-db-data-changes-in-angular-using-rxjs-or-anything)

If you are using the MongoDB as a database then you can try [minimongo packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-minimongo) it has a DB subscription for UI, but we have to take care of security threats