# Angular detect changes in API

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 devices, one running `Angular WebApp`, and 2nd only used to adding items to database. Both devices are connected to same REST API.

On first device I getting `JSON` containing items:

```json
[
{
"id": 42,
"item": "Jajka"
},
{
"id": 48,
"item": "Kapusta"
},
{
"id": 49,
"item": "Ziemniaki"
}
]
```

And on second device I performing `POST` action adding new item to database.

How should I check for changes on first device without refreshing page?

Fetching script:

```
  fetchData()
  {
    this.overlay = true;
    this.valuechanges = this.dataService.getRecipes()
    .subscribe(data => this.recipes$ = data);
    this.overlay = false;
  }
```

Fetching service:

```
export class DataService{
  apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/shoppinglists';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getItems() {
    return this._http.get<ShoppingList[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
```

Thanks for any answers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628416/listening-for-db-data-changes-in-angular-using-rxjs-or-anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I get what you want to do but you would have to use websockets for realtime communication or you can use polling.

```
interval(1000).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.dataService.getRecipes()),
    distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: `distinctUntilChanged()` will not work properly in this case

Answer (score 1):

You need some mechanism to notify devices that data changed on server. HTTP can't do that(or at least not good at doing that). One mature solution is WebSocket.

Basically you need WebSocket client and server. In Angular, you could use [rxjs/webSocket](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket) as the WebSocket client.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I will learn more about webSocket